# Why is the lowest TM mode 1,1?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, waveguide

I'm working on Griffiths problem 9.31 and he asks us to find the lowest TM mode in a rectangular wave guide… First, I need to deduce $E_z$. Using separation of variables I found that
$$ E_z(x,y) = E_0 \sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi y}{b}\right) $$
which necessarily implied that $$k = \sqrt{\left(\frac{w}{c}\right)^2 - \pi^2 [(m/a)^2 + (n/b)^2]}$$
just like with TE waves. I've checked my answer with both these equations. When discussing TE waves, Griffiths asserts that our lowest TE$_{mn}$ mode is TE$_{1,0}$ because we assume that $a \geq b$. This makes sense to me. However, when discussing TM waves in problem 9.31, the answer is somehow TM$_{1,1}$… that doesn't make sense to me. Why isn't it TM$_{1,0}$ like with TE waves?

Comment: Maybe homework/exercise question - but the question - why doesn't TM10 exist? - may be interesting?

Comment: This is implying that $E$ cannot be a simple sine function alone, but $B$ can exist as a simple cosine function alone… Not sure what that implies!

Answer (score 1):

The numbers after TE, TM indicate the index of the mode: n,m. You found that the wavenumbers: k$_x$ = mπ/a, k$_y$ = nπ/b, define these indices.

Consider if TM$_{1,0}$ were possible. Plugging into your expression for the TM mode,

$E_{z}^{TM}(x,y) = E_{0}$sin$(\frac{\pi x}{a})$sin$(0)$ = 0.

For TE modes,

$H_{z}^{TE}(x,y) = H_{0}$cos$(\frac{\pi x}{a})$cos$(0)$ = $H_{0}$cos$(\frac{\pi x}{a})$.

Thus due to the two sines of the TM mode, the wave disappears for any n or m = 0, but 1,0 are allowed for the TE modes due to the cosines.